# How do I combine multiple separate electronic devices onto one PCB?

Tags: arduino, pcb, pcb-design, prototyping

I'd like to create a PCB that has this I2C multiplexer on it, along with other components (resistors, external I2C device connections) that I deem necessary.

[image]

However, I don't know where to begin. I have schematics of the device and a footprint with dimensions, but I don't know how a PCB can be made with this device incorporated within it (without joining the separate device itself to a PCB.) Can I take each individual component and its wiring that I see on the schematic and add them into a PCB? How do I know that it will work properly?

This I2C multiplexer is just one example, but I'm interested in many different devices - Arduinos, sensors, etc.

Comment: Do you want to incorporate the schematics of that mux into your own PCB? Or do you want to physically incorporate that specific breakout board into your PCB? For the first, you put the schematic into the same schematic package as everythign else and it gets laid out on the PCB from scratch along with everything else. For the second you make a schematic component with the same pinouts as the breakout board and a make a footprint to match so that the entire breakout board appears as a new component (just like any other component) and do not need the schematic for the breakout board at all.

Comment: *How do I know that it will work properly?* - that's what EE is all about. When you begin about 10% of your designs work first time and the rest need anything from value changes to extensive track cuts and additions. About half of the 90% just get discarded and you move on recognizing your mistakes. As you grow more adept you'll get to the point where maybe 80% of stuff you design works out of the box with those that don't needing an odd value change and a bit of a reshuffle. If Olympic athletes asked how they are guaranteed to win gold the answer would be by competing and losing many times.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the schematic into some sort of CAD program. I use KiCad and do this all the time. First I generate a schematic and double check to be sure it is correct. The program will allow you to go from the schematic to a point where you assign packages (foot prints) to each of the components. You then save it as a netlist. You then go into the PCB layout section and import the netlist, it will also import the footprints. You can manually place each of the components, connect them together(routing), besure all SMD parts have the pads in the copper layer. When that looks ok you can add the trim lines and run then generate the Gerber files. Those you upload to your favorite PCB supplier. I use JLPCB but there are many others.

I would watch several of the tutorials on line, be cautious of your version, that will get you started. Make a few simple ones first, maybe a ic or two a connector just to get the feeling. It offers a 3D view so you can get an idea of what it will look like when finished.

This process will take several weeks for the first time through, it is like learning another language. Also be careful with which version of KiCad you use, use the latest, and it is free for downloading.

Comment: A note: a lot of software offers auto-routing or auto-layout tools. *Do not use them*. Autorouting may have been usable for the slow through-hole circuits of the 80s and 90s, but nowadays an autorouter can easily make a mess of what should be a controlled-impedance trace, or put vias in the weirdest of places, or otherwise just end up making more trouble than doing it manually.